# R, ggplot, color-coded segmented barcharts

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I am trying to come up with a way to plot the following graph in R. I have looked up a lot but did not find a solution.
[image]

This is an example of how data are:
`df<-data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow=20,ncol=3))  colnames(df)<-c("time","A","B")   df$time<-1:20 df$A<-c(rep("Success",3),rep("Fail",5),rep("Success",9),rep("Fail",3)) df$B<-c(rep("Success",7),rep("Fail",2),rep("Success",4),rep("Fail",7))`

Any help to create the plot in R would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach can be useful:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
#Code
df %>% pivot_longer(-time) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=time,y=name,fill=value))+
  geom_tile()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: great thanks! is there any way I could remove the black lines?

Comment: @ElmiraBerjisian Updated, hope that helps!